# symfony: do not login unverified user

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I have a short question on which i couldn't find an answer:
What is a correct way to deny a user with not validated email to log in using symfony 6.2

From the box Symfony allows user to log in no matter if his email was validated, even it requests user to log in first to validate his email by default. I've found the solution in adding additional param to confirmation url, so I can find current user and mark his email as valid without him logging in. But I still have a problem with symfony allowing user to log in without confirmed email and I'm stuck here. There are examples of how to check if user email is validated and deny actions if not, but no examples of how to deny loging in at all for users without validated email

Thanks for any help

I've tried to catch login event in event listener

```
app.login_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\LoginListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: afterSuccessLogin }
```

and i got it but I have no idea how to log of a user if his email is unverified and redirect him somewere else inside this event listener

***UPD***
I've Found a solution in registering an Event listener on security.authentication.success event and it works just fine

```
app.login_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\LoginListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onAuthenticationSuccessEvent }
```

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class LoginListener
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user->isVerified() === false)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException('You should first validate your email address.');
        }
    }
}
```

But definitely **the correct way is using Custom User Checker**, as Såpe recommended

Comment: This is described in full, with examples, in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html). You should create [Custom User Checkers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice that yet, by the way, I've found another way to solve my problem, added a LoginListener on security.authentication.success event, It works fine, but Custom User Checker is definetely what I was looking for